# Add gesture to custom view

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

May I add gesture recognizer on my custom view and handle it in this view? I want to carry out handling gestures logic from UIViewController, 
I've created custom class PrintView (inherited from UIView) which draw UIImageView itself and handles gestures, but it don't call any handlers:

```
self.showResizerGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
self.showResizerGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
self.showResizerGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1

self.ownPrint.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

self.showResizerGesture.delegate = self
self.ownPrint.addGestureRecognizer(self.showResizerGesture) ///
```

Comment: Please paste the  `self.handleTap(_:)` method.

Comment: Multiple ways to handle, implement protocol-delegate between customView and UIViewController 2. Use block 3. Pass viewController to customView (weak reference though) then in target use the ViewController instance

Comment: @objc func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("it called")
    }

Comment: try to add gestuer in `self.view`. if its worked then problem in your custom view

Comment: Yes, on self.view it works right, but I want to place it in my view hierarchy:
it should look like self.view.someImageview.addSubview(myCustomView)

Comment: what is ownPrint  instance? is it image view?

Comment: Yes, and I made its isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: where do you add this code? plus I don't think you need self. everywhere

Answer (score 1):

You may do so in principal. But following the *Model-View-Controller* paradigm used in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch, you should handle the gesture in the controller not in the view class. So set at least the delegate of the gesture recognizer to the view controller which uses this view. I would also add the recognizer to the view controller.